# How to change cmake install() patterns with parameters?

Tags: regex, cmake, installation

My CMake build system supports several platforms and configurations, and supports installing some files as well.

I'm using the install() command, as follows:

```
install(
 DIRECTORY <some path>
 DESTINATION <some other path>
 FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*" 
 PATTERN "<some regex 0>*" EXCLUDE
 PATTERN "<some regex 1>*" EXCLUDE
 ...
 PATTERN "<some regex N>*" EXCLUDE
)
```

Since I have several configuration, I'm looking for an easy way to use subsets of the regex patterns for each configuration, but without having to replicate the entire install command.

i.e.

```
install(
 DIRECTORY <some path>
 DESTINATION <some other path>
 FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*" 
 if (confiugrationA || configurationB)
      PATTERN "<some regex 0>*" EXCLUDE
 endif
 if (configurationC)
    PATTERN "<some regex 1>*" EXCLUDE
 endif()
 ...
 PATTERN "<some regex N>*" EXCLUDE
)
```

Can this be done? Can I use a special regular expression for that?

Answer (score 1):

Ended up using regex:

```
set(exclude_regex_A "patternA|patternB|...")
set(exclude_regex_B "patternC|patternD|...")
set(exclude_regex_C "patternE|patternF|...")
if (some_var)
 set(exclude_regex "${exclude_regex_A}|${exclude_regex_B}")
else (some_var)
 set(exclude_regex "${exclude_regex_A}|${exclude_regex_C}")
endif (some_var)
install(
 DIRECTORY <some path>
 DESTINATION <some other path>
 FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*" 
 REGEX "${exclude_regex}" EXCLUDE
)
```

Comment: Nice solution. 

Nitpicking: it's `REGEX "${exclude_regex}" EXCLUDE` not `regex "${exclude_regex}" EXCLUDE`